# How to rotate cartesian coordinates relative to a vector?

Tags: three.js, rotation

I'm building a fractal tree in three dimensions.  I need to draw each generation of branches at an angle relative to the previous generation.  The branches are currently drawn at the same angle and are growing "straight up".  I know I need to do a rotation of some kind, but not sure if it's quaternions or if I need to take a completely different approach.

Here's a jsfiddle of the fractal tree with the branches growing "straight up".
https://jsfiddle.net/degraeve/xa8m5Lcj/59/

Here's a 2D image of what I'm trying to achieve with the branch angles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Vnx.png

code that appears in the jsfiddle:

```
    function draw_tree_branch(x, y, z, phi, theta, radius) {
        // use sperical coordinate system
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system
        var phi_in_degrees = phi * (180 / Math.PI);
    
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ffff,
            linewidth: 1
        });
    
        // draw 3 lines at 120 degrees to each other
        var angle_between_branches = 120;
        var num_branches = 360 / angle_between_branches;
        for (var temp_count = 1; temp_count <= num_branches; temp_count++) {
    
            phi_in_degrees += angle_between_branches;
            phi = (phi_in_degrees) * Math.PI / 180;
            // compute Cartesian coordinates
            var x2 = x + (radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi));
            var y2 = y + (radius * Math.cos(theta));
            var z2 = z + (radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi));
    
            // ???????? 
            // How do I rotate this line so the angles are "relative" to the parent line instead of growing "straight up?"
            // Quaternion ???
            // example of what I'm trying to achieve, but in 3D:
            //   https://www.codheadz.com/2019/06/30/Trees-with-Turtle-in-Python/simple_tree.png
            // ????????
            var points = [];
            var vector_1 = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
            points.push(vector_1);
            var vector_2 = new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
            points.push(vector_2);
            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            scene.add(line);
    
            // keep drawing branches until the branch is "too short"
            if (radius > 2) {
                draw_tree_branch(x2, y2, z2, phi, theta, radius * 0.5);
            }
        }
    }
```

I may not even be asking the right question.  Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. The only problem is that `theta` is the same on each iteration, so you'll always get a sub-branch that's 30º from vertical. A simple way to solve this is by keeping track of the iteration you're in, and multiply that by `tree_theta` so you get an increasing number of degrees: 30, 60, 90, 120, etc...

```js
function draw_tree_branch(x, y, z, phi, tree_theta, radius, iteration) {
    var theta = tree_theta * iteration;

    // ... perform all calculations


    // Draw next branch with iteration + 1
    if (radius > 2) {
        draw_tree_branch(x2, y2, z2, phi, tree_theta, radius * 0.5, iteration + 1);
    }
}
```

Here's an updated version of your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/r2w7oz6x/

Comment: That's the trick - Theta needs to remain constant and the child branches are to be drawn at angle theta _relative_ to the parent branch.  I need to get the direction of the parent branch and rotate all the child branches by the parent branch's vector.  I just don't know three.js (or three dimension coordinate terminology) well enough to know which functions to use.